# Buttons and labels move to different positions when returning from phone call

Tags: ios, layout, uistoryboard

The App I am developing has buttons to make calls. After returning from a call some buttons and labels move to the bottom of the view (keep their x position, proper width and height). I am not using auto-layout and programmatically setting the position of all elements. Only phone calls seem to have this affect as switching to different Apps, home screen, etc do not do this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [topBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 29)];
    [mapLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(70, 5, 125, 18)];
    [mapSubLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(70, 24, 125, 14)];
    [centerMapImage setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 50, 44)];
    [dialPhoneButton setFrame:CGRectMake(256, 0, 50, 44)];
}
```

The last two are the ones that move when returning from a phone call.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Could you show us your code?

Comment: Just check if you don't set the position of your subviews in viewDidAppear or viewWillApear. In this case these method are called after the call is finished and your view is changed.